# Does anyone have experience with Community Exchange Systems?

Tags: currency, trading, services

I am interested to know if anyone has participated in a Community Exchange System, where the currency of exchange of goods and services is completely information-based - in other words, there is not physical currency - only a local record of giving and receiving goods and services.

See this website for a more detailed description: http://www.ces.org.za

I am interested only in one's own personal experience from actually participating in a CES - not in hypothetical diatribes.

Marking this community wiki, since there is no 1 correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a "time bank" and it works.

Comment: May I ask approx. how many transactions you've participated in, and perhaps how many members were in your community exchange?